# Geddy - create new item

Tags: node.js, geddy

I am an absolute beginner in node.js and geddy. I've followed a few tutorials and now I try to write something similar for my purposes.

When I try to create a new item, though, I get the following message:

```
/arithmetic_problem_types/function%20(id)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20options.id%20=%20id;%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20helpersBase.urlFor.action(options);%20%20%20%20%7D not found.
```

I have no idea where this could come from. I've looked through the code and found nothing.

Controller:

```
var ArithmeticProblemTypes = function () {
  this.respondsWith =[ 'html', 'json', 'xml', 'js', 'txt'];

  this.index = function (req, resp, params) {
    var self = this;

    geddy.model.ArithmeticProblemType.all(function (err, arithmetic_problem_types) {
        self.respond({
            params: params, arithmetic_problem_types: arithmetic_problem_types
        });
    });
  };

  this.add = function (req, resp, params) {
    this.respond({
        params: params
    });
  };

  this.create = function (req, resp, params) {
    var self = this, arithmetic_problem_type = geddy.model.ArithmeticProblemType.create({
        name: '1', title: 'open', numberType: '1', numberRanges: '1', operators: '1', askedFor: '1', specialProblemCategory: '1', askedForNumDenomOrBoth: '1',
            reducedFractions:'1', mixedFractions: '1'
    });

    arithmetic_problem_type.save(function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            params.errors = err;
            self.transfer('add');
        } else {
            self.redirect({
                controller: self.name
            });
        }
    });
  };
....................................................................
};

exports.ArithmeticProblemTypes = ArithmeticProblemTypes;
```

add.html.ejs

```
<div class="hero-unit">
  <%= partial('_form', {params: params}); %>
</div>
```

index.html.ejs

```
<div class="hero-unit">
  <h2>Arithmetic Problem Types List</h2>
  <%- linkTo('Create a new Aritmetic Problem Type', addArithmeticProblemTypePath, {class: 'btn pull-right'}) %>
</div>
<% if (arithmetic_problem_types && arithmetic_problem_types.length) { %>
  <% for (var i in arithmetic_problem_types) { %>
  <div class="row todo-item">
    <div class="span8">
      <h3><%- linkTo(arithmetic_problem_types[i].title, arithmeticProblemTypePath(arithmetic_problem_types[i].id)) %></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="span4"><h3><i class="icon-list-alt"></i><%= arithmetic_problem_types[i].status; %></h3></div>
  </div>
 <% } %>
<% } %>
```

How can I get rid of that message and make it work?

**EDIT:**
This is the beginning of the _form.html.ejs file:

```
<%
  var isUpdate = params.action == 'edit'
, formTitle = isUpdate ? 'Update this Arithmetic Problem Type' : 'Create a new Arithmetic Problem Type'
, action = isUpdate ? arithmeticProblemTypePath(params.id) + '?_method=PUT' : arithmeticProblemTypePath
, deleteAction = isUpdate ? arithmeticProblemTypePath(params.id) + '?_method=DELETE' : ''
, btnText = isUpdate ? 'Update' : 'Add'
, nameValue = isUpdate ? arithmeticProblemTypePath.name : ''
, errors = params.errors;
%>
<form id="arithmetic-problem-type-form" class="form-horizontal" action="<%= action %>" method="POST">
     ....
</form>
```

**EDIT2:**
Inspecting the page where I should write the name of the item and click the add button, I've found this

```
<div class="hero-unit">

  <form id="arithmetic-problem-type-form" class="form-horizontal" action="function (id) {
      options.id = id;
      return helpersBase.urlFor.action(options);
    }" method="POST">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Create a new Arithmetic Problem Type</legend>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label for="title" class="control-label">Title</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input class="span6" name="name" placeholder="enter name" type="text">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Add">

    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

Indeed the message comes from the action attribute of the form element, but how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is telling you that the requested URL could not be found. AKA 404

`/arithmetic_problem_types/function%20(id)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20options.id%20=%20id;%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20helpersBase.urlFor.action(options);%20%20%20%20%7D`

is definitely not a nice looking url. So i'm assuming there's something wrong with your form's `action` attribute. If that's what happened when you validate the form.

If that's what happened when you click the link to "Create a new arithmetic problem type" then you should probably put parenthesis after `addArithmeticProblemTypePath`

Comment: when does this message happen?

Comment: when I click on the ADD button

Comment: then same answer 
you should probably put parenthesis after addArithmeticProblemTypePath

Comment: how is it not that ?

` action = isUpdate ? arithmeticProblemTypePath(params.id) + '?_method=PUT' : arithmeticProblemTypePath`

Comment: you mean I should write ' action = isUpdate ? arithmeticProblemTypePath(params.id) + '?_method=PUT' : arithmeticProblemTypePath()' ?

Comment: yes. obvisouly the action in your form is the body of a javascript function. it only means that you should _call_ that helper and print the returned value of it

Comment: the tutorial from geddyjs.org doesn't have paranthesis and the app worked fine...now I'm not getting that message anymore, but my app crashes... [See here](http://s23.postimage.org/sea97clln/geddy_error.png)

Comment: reading the geddy tutorial. I notice they use todoPath(id) and todosPath.
So, my bad, you should use `arithmeticProblemTypesPath` instead of `arithmeticProblemTypePath`

Comment: I've already tried that...but the app crashes with the same error as the one posted in my previous comment

Comment: the error was caused by a data type in my model... but my initial problem could be also fixed also by adding paranthesis at the end, instead of writing arithmeticProblemTypesPath...thanks!

Comment: I have another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274596/display-only-some-of-the-parameters)...please take a look