# Display only the desired parameters

Tags: node.js, geddy

I created an app following [this tutorial](http://geddyjs.org/tutorial) (without scaffolding).

After I create an item I can click on it and it shows me a big list of parameters. Like here: http://s15.postimage.org/j6at9koiz/parameters.png .

The code which does that is:

```
<% if (todos && todos.length) { %>
  <% for (var i in todos) { %>
  <div class="row todo-item">
    <div class="span8">
        <h3><%- linkTo(todos[i].title, todoPath(todos[i].id)) %></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="span4"><h3><i class="icon-list-alt"></i><%= todos[i].status; %></h3></div>
  </div>
  <% } %>
<% } %>
```

To be more specific, the following line is the one which displays the links with the titles which take me to the list of the parameters for each item:

```
<%- linkTo(todos[i].title, todoPath(todos[i].id)) %>
```

Can I do something to display only some of the parameters and not the entire list which is displayed now?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add view files for todo resource. If you're scaffolding, then geddy creates them by default. But otherwise, you have to add view files for todo in `app/views/todos`.

View files

- _form.html.ejs

  - edit/new form
- add.html.ejs

  - new resource view
  - `/todos/add`
- edit.html.ejs

  - edit view
  - `/todos/:id/edit`
- index.html.ejs

  - index view
  - `/todos`
- show.html.ejs

  - show individual resource
  - `/todos/:id`

You can edit them manually. For changing how a individual todo item should appear on `/todos/:id` route, edit `show.html.ejs`

```
<div class="hero-unit">
  <%- linkTo('Edit this todo', editTodoPath(params.id), {class: 'btn pull-right'}); %>
  <h3>Params</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>todo.title</li>
    <li>todo.property1</li>
    <li>todo.property2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: and how can I display only the parameters defined in the model?

Comment: so there is not something that can do this automatically?...a function or something that returns only the field of the model or return a boolean value checking if the parameter is from the model?

Comment: your idea is also good, but I did it by creating an array with the desired parameters and then checked if the current parameter is in that array and, if it is, it is diplayed